# How to make nodes semi-transparent

Tags: node-editor

In

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/compositing/types/converter/id_mask.html

the viewer node seems to be semi-transparent, letting background link visible. How to set it ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust node backdrop color in:

*Preferences > Themes > Node Editor*

[image]

Comment: Super, thank you.